# Classical bit-fiddling tricks that don't work in the EVM

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, defi, yul

Many classical bit-fiddling/bit-hacking tricks work very well on the EVM and allow one to save a significant amount of gas when programming in Yul/Solidity (for a reference to the classics, see Sean Anderson list of [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) or the book [Hacker's Delight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker%27s_Delight); For EVM-centric discussion which includes gas computation see Remco Bloemen's [2π webpage](https://xn--2-umb.com/)).

I was wondering if anybody can share from their experience (or perhaps is there an opposite list?) what tricks or numerical algorithms were useful in x86-64 architecture but are a ''dead end" when trying to optimize computations in the EVM - either for gas reasons or because of the existence of different opcodes which makes them obsolete.

Comment: Interesting question, but I think the scope is too broad for the Stack Exchange format. Finding such a list of tricks that "don't work" is basically a research project.

Comment: @kfx Yes, I know :-) I just want to know if someone has already done this research project, and if so - where it has been published.

Comment: I think most codes should work because they only depend on a two complement machine, which the EVM follows. You'll need some care when writing them because the words are 256 bits, and the assembly language are not the same. I've seem some of the tricks used in contracts (log 2, min-max), I haven't seen a compilation of those tricks. It should be an interesting writing for someone learning about the EVM.

Comment: Here is a article with some bit tricks https://saxenism.com/web3/solidity/language-tricks/bit-magic/intermediate/2022/09/06/Bit-Magic-Solidity.html